# multiply lists in R talking inners variables

Tags: r, list

I have a `list1=[2,4,7]`, and a `list2=[5,7,8,10]`

I need repeted the first element of list1 times the first element of list2. The list don't have the same length.

Comment: I think you want `?outer`

Comment: I have for example numbers and totals. Numbers in list 1, total in list 2. I need an output like this (5,5,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8). I do a correction, I have list with same size.